# Call method from C# backend into javascript react frontend

Tags: reactjs, .net, web, web-applications, bridge

I have a webapp built using reactjs for frontend and .NET6 for the backend part and now I want to use the logic in the backend to display a result of a method into front end. What could help me do that, is there a framework or method to create a bridge to a specific method in the backend so I could get the results in the frontend ?

Comment: do you mean make an http request?

Comment: I have a form on my front end and when I submit it I want to call a method from the backend and alert the client of the result...

Comment: yeah so you need to expose a REST endpoint in your backend and submit the form via an HTTP request on the front end

Comment: So there is no other way of doing this without having a REST API ?

Comment: whatever you use it needs to connect the computer that runs your front end with the computer that runs your backend. so choose whatever internet protocol you want, REST / sockets etc. REST is definitely the easiest and most common

Comment: the most common way, send ajax in the frontend to the api in the backend. I agree with @azium